# How to covert json value in to html table

Tags: html, json, datatable

I want json code and also how to convert that json data to html table. Importantly how to covert the json values as a th(header) in html.
[image]

Comment: What backend language are you using?

Comment: Please put the code you have tried

Comment: Do you use JavaScript @Gokul

Answer (score 0):

In case you use JS.

Try this out build your table as string and then insert it in the element,

```js
const json = [{
    code: 101,
    attribute: "Body",
    attribute_values: "S101"
  },
  {
    code: 102,
    age: "float",
    attribute_values: "S102"
  }
]

function buildTable() {

  let tab = `<table><thead><tr><th>Code</th><th>Body</th></tr></thead><tbody>`
   
  json.forEach((elem) => {
  tab += `<tr><td>${elem.code}</td><td>${elem.attribute_values}</td></tr> `
  });
  
  tab += `</tbody></table>`

 document.getElementById("insTab").innerHTML = tab;
  
}
buildTable();
```

```html
<div id="insTab"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/nt56wuox/3/ for a basic example in pure javascript and HTML.

Html

```
<html>
<body>
  <input id='inAttr' type='text' placeholder='Enter attr' >
  <button onClick='calculate(document.getElementById("inAttr").value)' > Show table  </button>
  <div id='result'>  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
data = [
{code:'101' , attr:'Body' , attr_value: 'SS04'},
{code:'102' , attr:'Body' , attr_value: 'SS04'},
{code:'103' , attr:'Float' , attr_value: 'SS0X'},
{code:'104' , attr:'Spring' , attr_value: 'SS0X'},
]

function calculate(attr){

  const tableData = data
  .filter(row=>row.attr === attr)
    
  console.log({attr, tableData}); 
  
  var html = '<table>';
  html+=`<tr><th>Code</th><th>${attr}</th></tr>`
  tableData.forEach(row=>{
  html+=`<tr><td>${row.code}</td><td>${row.attr_value}</td></tr>`
  })
  html += '<table>';

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
  return tableData;
}
```

You might want to consider reading about HTML, JS and JSON and perhaps one of the common frameworks such as Angular / React